# Dynamic filtering of a table with value from a textbox in multiple column with OR operator

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, filtering, excel-365

I am trying to develop a search functionality in a worksheet, related to a dynamic filtering via VBA

EXPECTED RESULT :
When I start typing in a textbox, a table is filtered if what I write is in column 1 OR in column 2.

---

In the worksheet I have a table (G10:J78) called "tbl_Data"

I insert a Textbox (name is TextBox1) on cell D8 and linked it to D8 so that what I write in the textbox is written in D8.
Then, in the TextBox1 code, I wrote :

```
Private Sub TblBox_Change()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_Data")
.Range.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=("*" & (d8) & "*"), Operator:=xlOr 
.Range.Autofilter field:=2, Criteria1:=("*" & (d8) & "*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues 
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is solution does not work, as it only works with first column (field:=1).

Anyone has a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

give this a try.

```
Private Sub TblBox_Change()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim trgtRng As Range
Dim table As ListObject

Set table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_Data")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With table
    .Range.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=("*" & (d8) & "*"), Operator:=xlOr
    Set trgtRng = .DataBodyRange
    If trgtRng Is Nothing Then
        'if there are no results then you need to clear the filter first
        If (ws.AutoFilterMode And ws.FilterMode) Or ws.FilterMode Then
          ws.ShowAllData
        End If
        ' and then you need to apply the filter on the second column
        .Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=("*" & (d8) & "*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If
End With

set ws = nothing
set table = nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```